# Efficient multiprocessing file parsing with deduplication between processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, clickhouse

The job is to parse hundreds of GBs of files (millions of small files) and insert them into a database.
To do that job efficiently, it is possible to split the files between a large number of processes so each handles a chunk of files.

The issue is that the database (ClickHouse) does not support unique primary key and ReplacingMergeTree table engine which is supposed to handle duplicates is not reliable. Therefore duplicates should be handled before the insert.

The challenge lies in communicating between processes.
I have tried two approaches that have failed:

1. Implement a shared set of IDs
2. Implement a queue that reading/transforming processes write to after processing files which a single central process reads from and filters out duplicates

Both processes suffer from a similar problem - they spend majority of time waiting for access to queue or shared set once certain amount of files were processed. There is a certain block size set which triggers insert into the database. It is necessary because otherwise RAM would run out. Once all threads reach that block size for the first time, the execution comes to a standstill because writing/reading from queue or shared set cannot keep up with the speed of 30+ processes processing files.

What is a proper efficient way to implement this